# python / pandas - referencing the last column of a dataframe without typing it's name in a groupby calculation

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, reference, pandas-groupby

I have:

```
dat['P: EU - returns - PL']  =  ecommerce_returns * delivery_emissions_per_return * social_cost_of_carbon  
dat['P: EU - returns - Per Product Line'] = dat.iloc[:,-1] * dat[n_sold]
dat['P: EU - returns - CL'] = dat.groupby(group_with)['P: EU - returns - Per Product Line'].transform('sum')
```

Which I will have to repeat many times. Instead of typing the name of the last column of the `dataframe` , `dat`, i would like to reference it. I can do it when the calculation does not involve a `groupby` but, I can't find a way to do it with a `groupby`.

I tried:

```
dat['P: EU - returns - CL'] = dat.groupby(group_with).dat.iloc[:,-1].transform('sum')
```

But I was 100% that it wouldn't work.  Any workarounds? Thank you

Comment: i provided a low IQ solution that will work

Comment: given that my question was low IQ too your answer is definitely acceptable

Comment: let me know if it works haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data.groupby("blabla")[data.columns[-1]]
```

`[data.columns[-1]]` will provide the name of the last column inside brackets which is compatible with `groupby`